# Unable to cast C# object in F# type

Tags: c#, f#, c#-to-f#

I have the following declaration in F#:

```
type ConstArg =
    | Bool of bool
    | CharArray of char[]

member Lambda (ConstArg : ConstArg[]) = ...
```

In C#, I have constructed a char[] array of two values:

```
char[][] list = new char[][] {firstArray, secondArray};
```

I do want to call `.Lambda(list)` but I am unable to convert list into `ConstArg[]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

F# discriminated union type in C# is a class with static creational methods `NewXXX` for discriminated union cases. In your case there will be method with signature

```
public static ConstArg NewCharArray(char[] item)
```

You should use this method to convert each char array to an instance of `ConstArg` type:

```
Lambda(list.Select(ConstArg.NewCharArray).ToArray())

// or without LINQ
Lambda(Array.ConvertAll(list, ConstArg.NewCharArray))
```

Note that parameter names in F# should be camel-case as per [naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/style-guide/component-design-guidelines#naming-conventions)

Comment: That's great! Thanks @Sergey.
Do you have an idea if my `list` is a mix of the unions (i.e: [CharArray, Bool]) and I want to create a lambda with a generic `ConstArg`?

Comment: @islamhamdi your list will contain `ConstArg` objects because both `CharArray` and `Bool` are instances of `ConstArg` type. So there will be no problem to pass it to lambda.